# Multi array in php

Tags: php

i have a problem with array in php
example:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
b=[2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]
```

I like to have following from a and b

```
 c = [ [1,2016],[2,2017],[3,2018],[4,2019],[5,2020] ]
```

How to do that?Thank so much.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: if that is suppose to be code, its invalid

Comment: Your code is javascript?

Comment: Please share your try ?

Comment: zonelog Don't add thank you message as an answer not correct. 2. Instead of it mark the right answer as correct answer. check here how to do it:- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work . 3. So delete your answer and mark the othe answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This code will set `$c` to the structure you wanted:

```
<?php
$a = [1,2,3,4,5];
$b = [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020];

$c = [];
foreach (array_keys($a) as $i) {
    $c[] = [$a[$i], $b[$i]];
}

print_r($c);
```

The output is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2016
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2017
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 2018
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 2019
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 2020
        )

)
```

Or get it as you formatted it with `json_encode($c)`:

```
[[1,2016],[2,2017],[3,2018],[4,2019],[5,2020]]
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't like looping you can use array_merge_recursive if you do some manipulation with the arrays first.
Array_merge_recursive only works with associative arrays, so I make an array with A,B,C.. that I combine with the input arrays, this makes array_merge recursive work as expected.
The I use array_values to remove the associative keys.
Just as the other solutions, this expects equal lenghts of arrays.

```
$a=[1,2,3,4,5];
$b=[2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020];

$keys = range("A", chr(64+count($a))); // [A,B,C,D,E]
$c = array_values(array_merge_recursive(array_combine($keys,$a),array_combine($keys,$b)));
Var_dump($c);
```

https://3v4l.org/qHCGI

I honestly think this is slower than looping on your arrays, maybe with a larger array times will be more equal.
This was mostly posted as "it works without looping" not as a quicker alternative.